# What is the maximum limit of JSON Length when running SELECT from MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, aggregate, group-concat

i have a table with 8 columns and 62,000+ rows. i'd like MySQL to convert its table defition to JSON via the select statement which i do by:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        '[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'json_column_name', tbl.actual_column_name,
                ...
            )
        ),
        ']'
    )
FROM
    table_name tbl;
```

However, the JSON is cut once it reaches the 4th row from the table, this even with `LIMIT 2` declared for testing (which i don't understand because i've limited to first 2 rows). i already increased my `max_allowed_packets` to 1GB but still, the JSON gets cut.

Comment: Did you also SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len ?

Comment: like @P.Salmon already suggested [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has a limit of 1024 what i generally do when needing `GROUP_CONCAT` is using `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len  = @@max_allowed_packet`

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry, didn't know of that, i'll have a look at it. i was actually trying JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(...)) but for some reason, it returns me a null value.

Answer (score 0):

The limit for a JSON document is set by the MySQL protocol's limit of max_allowed_packet to roughly 1GB.  You can use the JSON_STORAGE_SIZE function before trying to write to the sever to test to see if what you are trying to put into the column is over that size.

And if it is you may be able to split it over multiple columns of 1GB components.